# Orderer disconnections in a Hyperledger Fabric application

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We have a hyperledger application. The main application is hosted on AWS VM's whereas the DR is hosted on Azure VM's. Recently the Microsoft Team identified that one of the DR VM's became unavailable and the availability was restored in approximately 8 minutes. As per Microsoft "This unexpected occurrence was caused by an Azure initiated auto-recovery action. The auto-recovery action was triggered by a hardware issue on the physical node where the virtual machine  was hosted. As designed, your VM was automatically moved to a different and healthy physical node to avoid further impact." The Zookeeper VM was also redeployed at the same

The day after this event occurred, we have started noticing that an orderer goes offline and immediately comes online after a few seconds. This disconnection/connection occurs regularly after a gap of 12 hours and 10 minutes.

We have noticed two things

In the log we get

```
 - [orderer/consensus/kafka] startThread -> CRIT 24df#033[0m [channel:
   testchainid] Cannot set up channel consumer = kafka server: The
   requested offset is outside the range of offsets maintained by the
   server for the given topic/partition.
 - panic: [channel: testchainid] Cannot set up channel consumer = kafka
   server: The requested offset is outside the range of offsets
   maintained by the server for the given topic/partition.
 - goroutine 52 [running]:
 - github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Panicf(0xc4202748a0,
   0x108dede, 0x31, 0xc420327540, 0x2, 0x2)
 - /w/workspace/fabric-binaries-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging/logger.go:194
   +0x134
 - github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/kafka.startThread(0xc42022cdc0)
 - /w/workspace/fabric-binaries-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/kafka/chain.go:261
   +0xb33
 - created by
   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/kafka.(*chainImpl).Start
 - /w/workspace/fabric-binaries-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/kafka/chain.go:126
   +0x3f
```

Another thing which we noticed is that, in logs prior to the VM failure event  there were 3 kafka brokers but we can see only 2 kafka brokers in the logs after this event.

Can someone guide me on this? How do I resolve this problem?

**Additional information -** We have been through the Kafka logs of the day after which the VM was redeployed and we noticed the following

```
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1195725856 larger than 104857600)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:132)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:231)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:528)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:469)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:398)
at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:535)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:452)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional details on how your Kafka and ZK nodes are deployed across AWS and Azure?

Comment: @GariSingh Thanks for responding. Can you please let me know as to which details are you specifically looking for?

Comment: Sure:    1) How many Kafka brokers in your cluster?  2) Is your Kafka cluster spread across both AWS and Azure?

Comment: We are running three kafka nodes and three zookeeper nodes, two of each on AWS and 1 of each on Azure, configured across a VPN.     Multiple orderers continue to communicate fine with the entire Kafka infrastructure, however, the one orderer that was hosted on the faulty Azure node is the only one exhibiting this condition of failing every 12 hours 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we have a solution but it needs to be validated. Once the solution is validated, I will post it on this site.

Comment: Hi! Have you ever validated your solution? Can you share it? Facing the same issue and not sure how to proceed. Thanks.